# What value does WebORB add when accessing a .NET service?

Tags: .net, apache-flex, flex4, weborb

I've been reading about [WebORB](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-net), and am wondering: if I just need to call methods on a .NET web service from my Flex app, does it add any value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value is that it allows you to call existing .NET web service methods using AMF, a binary format which should drastically reduce the quantity of data transferred and make parsing quicker for Flex (since it's a native format) compared to traditional communications (XML and JSON).

If you're familiar with BlazeDS, WebORB is the .NET version.

Answer (score 1):

It adds alot of value.
you can auto-generate the code to communicate with your services
you can use AMF and by that dramatically reduce the traffic to and from your server thus upping the performance.
You can also push data to the client, you can sync clients and do many more things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it also as a proxy service, if you are not allowed to have a crossdomain file on that server.